# Google Charts Not working on Desktop Browsers, but fine on Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization, cdn, cloudflare

All of a sudden, Google Charts stopped working on Desktop browsers, but they work on Mobile. I have not done any changes in the 6 months, but something very weird. I have moved the DNS to cloudflare recently and not sure, if thats the issue. The hosting provider said all is fine. I am really confused and stuck on what to do. 
Below are the URLs : 
http://redbus2us.com/trackers/h1b-visa-tracker/
http://redbus2us.com/trackers/h4-visa-ead-tracker/
Also, some of the other php pages are getting stuck too at load stage on desktop browsers, I am very much confused... Here are the pages : http://redbus2us.com/green-card-sponsors/ , http://redbus2us.com/h1b-visa-sponsors/

Comment: I had the same issue and it was with Cloudflare's rocket loader.

Answer (score 1):

Everyone, The issue was due to the Cloudflare's Rocket Loader Feature that was not working. I disabled the rocket loader and minify html, css and javascript option as well, it works back to normal.  The support told that rocket loader is in beta, so may have issues. 
Thank for your attention.